# nhibernate cant not save or SaveOrUpdate

Tags: nhibernate

It took me so much time . Im lost in it .
I make the program read from a XML and deserialize it to Object with the primary key 'id' .But using both 'SaveOrUpdate' and 'Save' method  cant not make the data insert into database . 
and Log4Net not error. no insert log. no exception happened.
Somebody helps me.

Today I tried to add a primary key 'HotelId' in the table and it's identity ,and works .
How to make it work  without an extra primary key. 
because the id in XML is unique. so I do not wanna add extra primary key.

fllowing is part of  *.hbm.xml

```
 <id name="id" column="id" type="string"  >
     <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
    <property name="dateUpdated" column="dateUpdated" type="DateTime"  />
    <property name="name" column="name" type="string"  />
    <property name="address" column="address" type="string"  />
    <property name="zip" column="zip" type="string"  />
```

while I add a extra primary not in XML ,it works like following :

```
<id name="Id" column="HotelId" type="int" unsaved-value="0"  >
     <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="id" column="id" type="string"  />
    <property name="dateUpdated" column="dateUpdated" type="DateTime"  />
    <property name="name" column="name" type="string"  />
    <property name="address" column="address" type="string"  />
    <property name="zip" column="zip" type="string"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

my crystal ball tells me you do not use `transactions.Commit();` nor `session.Flush();` to tell the session you have done your work and want the changes persisted. I Hope it's not broken